# setup:upgrade is throwing error

Tags: magento2, upgrade, fatal-error

When I try to do a `setup upgrade` using the below command, it throws a PHP Fatal Error:

```
$ sudo bin/magento setup:upgrade
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught TypeError: Argument 1 passed to Magento\Framework\Config\Scope::__construct() must be an instance of Magento\Framework\App\AreaList, instance of Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\ObjectManager given, called in /var/www/magento2/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php on line 97 and defined in /var/www/magento2/vendor/magento/framework/Config/Scope.php:37
Stack trace:
#0 /var/www/magento2/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php(97): Magento\Framework\Config\Scope->__construct(Object(Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\ObjectManager))
#1 /var/www/magento2/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Compiled.php(88): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory->createObject('Magento\\Framewo...', Array)
#2 /var/www/magento2/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/ObjectManager.php(71): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Compiled->create('Magento\\Framewo...')
#3 /var/www/magento2/vendor/magento/framework/App/ObjectManager/Environment/Com in /var/www/magento2/vendor/magento/framework/Config/Scope.php on line 37
```

When I launch the site in browser it's showing 500 error, and the same error message is shown on the apache error log.

Is there any way to reset Magento to fresh install state without any extra modules?

Comment: try with sudo php bin/magento setup:upgrade

Comment: If your creating any module then please share your code as  there will be problem in your code you have to define it in   public function __construct() to use

Comment: i have removed the custom plugin and tried upgrade but still its showing same error

Answer (score 2):

Usually you receive this error when you have changed some dependency injections and your var/di/ is out of date.

I would recommend deleting the `var/di` folder and then run:

```
php bin/magento setup:di:compile
```

Comment: The 'php bin/magento setup:di:compile' step is not mandatory, though. Magento can also generate files it needs on the fly, so you don't have to wait for the entire di to be compiled each time you change some dependencies.

Comment: i have run the php bin/magento setup:di:compile but same error is repeating

Comment: Did you update the magento version? Maybe your framework module is corrupt?

Comment: current version is 2.0.2

Comment: after some googling i have deleted entire var folder and some how able to run setup:upgrade and setup:di:compile but var/generate folder is missing

Comment: It's probably a permissions problem. You can set 775 or 777 (for development purposes only, never use such permissions on production!) on the var directory and check if it solved the missing var/generation directory problem.

Answer (score 0):

Disable your custom modules and find out from which module it is coming.

Debug the configuration files of that module for the error.

As this is an error in xml file.

Comment: previously i have added a plugin and then i have removed that so it shouldn't be affecting right?. right now there is no extra plugin, only magento default modules

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this same issue.  After performing a compile, any call to the Magento command line would fail as you describe.  In my case it was because I was attempting to use PHP 7.0.5

The Magento system requirements state:
"There is a known PHP issue that affects our code compiler when using PHP 7.0.5. We recommend you not use PHP 7.0.5."
http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/install-gde/system-requirements.html

Hope this helps!

Comment: UPDATE: It appears that this bug was fixed in PHP 7.0.6, however the Magento site does not yet list 7.0.6 as "supported".  I am currently running under 7.0.6 in my development environment and will report back if I run into any issues.

Comment: UPDATE #2: It looks like Magento is also addressing this on their end, and should have a fix in the next release:
https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/3963